# Codeigniter 404 page issue with bonfire

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp, bonfire

I have facing the 404 page issue in codeigniter on localhost.

I have also set rewrite_mode enable on appache and if I have disable rewrite_mode than it gives 500 error. 
Also set .htaccess file.

```
  DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# condition with escaping special chars
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Appache hhtpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/newpro/public" 
ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me for the same.
Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you share some code

Comment: Yes, I have added htaccess code on above and here my appache httpd.conf file code                                                             
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/newpro/public"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Please look up how to create a proper Virtual Host  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: For a start you dont add a VH definition into the `httpd.conf` file.